# Nose framework: avoid to include scipy.stats in test with coverage

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import, nose, nosetests

Inside my project, there is a folder with tests for all the `python` modules of the project. The tests are implemented through `unittest`.

When I want to test the code, I use `nose`, and I run from terminal:

```
$ cd test_folder/
$ nosetests
```

and everything is ok. When I want to have the information about the code coverage performed by the tests, I run the following

```
$ nosetests --with-coverage
```

However, inside one of my `.py` modules, I use `scipy.stats` module, that I import by

```
from scipy import stats
```

because

```
import scipy
scipy.stats.foo()
```

does [not work](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/api.html). The problem is that, when I run the tests with coverage, the coverage analysis is printed also for the entire `scipy` and event `numpy` modules. Thus, the output of the coverage-test is unreadable: hundreds of lines about the coverage of those modules.

Output example:

```
...
numpy.polynomial.polytemplate                     6      1    83%   16
numpy.polynomial.polyutils                       73     53    27%   76-80, 106-112, 156-179, 226-234, 274-280, 323-327, 392-394
numpy.random                                      9      1    89%   98
numpy.random.info                                 2      0   100%   
numpy.version                                     7      1    86%   10
...
scipy.interpolate.info                            1      0   100%   
scipy.io.info                                     1      0   100%   
scipy.lib                                         3      0   100%   
scipy.lib.blas                                   49     36    27%   16-17, 26-65
scipy.lib.blas.info                               0      0   100%   
scipy.lib.info                                    1      0   100%   
...
```

Do you know how to avoid that `nosetests --with-coverage` outputs the coverage stats about `numpy` and `scipy` modules?

Answer (score 1):

You can import stats from scipy using following syntax:

```
import scipy.stats
scipy.stats.foo()
```

You can restrict coverage report with --cover-package option. So, if your code is in app package, the invocation would be:

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=app tests/
```